# How to navigate from review to the original message?

Tags: feature-request, review

I assume that it is possible, but I cannot find it (I actually had to use Google to find the original message I was supposed to review).

So, if this is possible, please, make this option stand out more in the UI.
If this isn't possible, please, make it possible.

### Why this is needed

1. Review doesn't show comments.
2. It is more convenient to read the message w/o the diff.
3. If I find myself needing to message the author or the editor to make a decision about the edit, it's really hard to do so w/o having a link to the original post.

Comment: Which review item did you have trouble with? I find it obvious for all the review types I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the title. If the review item is a question, the title appears at the top of the content. If the review is for a suggested edit on an answer, the title appears above the answer. If the review is for a late or low quality answer, the title appears at the top of the question, below the answer. For a suggested edit on a tag wiki, a title containing a link to the list of questions and a link to the rendered tag wiki appears above the content.

Comment: That's another part of the problem: the review doesn't display the title of the message. The review is on an edit to a question.

Comment: @wvxvw The review should display the title, even if it hasn't changed. I see the title on [this](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7202) (after the fact) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14043466) (pending), for example. Could you link to a problematic review item? Do you use any browser userscripts?

Comment: OK, then it must be some browser / server rendering glitch. The one I had looked differently. At the top it had two buttons to switch between Markdown / parsed views and I don't remember what the other button was, but it didn't show the title.

Comment: I'll wait until there's a similar situation and will add a screenshot.

Comment: Hm. I saw review request today, and it had a title, which was a link to the original question. Maybe it was some kind of a browser / rendering glitch... anyhow, it doesn't seem to happen anymore.